# Angular CLI in ASP.NET core with hot module replacement

Tags: asp.net-core, angular-cli, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

We want to use Angular CLI for our projects within ASP.NET core. As output we choose wwwroot instead of dist. The default ng serve enables hot module replacement automatically. But now we need to have hot module replacement with kestrel and iis integration. We decided not to use the AspNet core Javascriptservices because we want to use Angular CLI as the default.

Does anyone know how to do enable hot module replacement with Angular CLI and the ASP.NET core standard hostring with staticfiles within the wwwroot?

Comment: Definitely interested in this as well. Did you ever find a solution stephan.peters?

Comment: We are going to use angular cli to host the client app (js, CSS, html...) and use iis kestrel for web api on local host with 2 different ports and cors enabled. So we are not looking for a profound integration between the two anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run angular cli with these steps.

1. Make sure you have latest [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links) install on your system.
2. Create asp.net core angular template project in Visual Studio 2017.
3. Now update all the npm packages with [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)
4. Install npm packages with

   > `npm install`
5. Install angular/cli globally

   > `npm install @angular/cli@latest -g`
6. Install angular/cli locally

   > `npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev`
7. Create an angular project outside your main project on any temp location with this command:

   > `ng new hello-world`
8. Now, go to project directory and copy `.angular-cli.json` file into the root of your main dot net core project.
   Then you have to edit this part of the file:

   > `"root" : "src"`  change to  `"root" : "ClientApp"`

Everythings was done!

Now, go to your **component directory** of your project:

> `cd ClientApp/app/components`

and make your component in **component directory** in terminal:

> `ng g c MyComponent --module='app.module.browser.ts'`

Comment: And can u run ng serve (webpack dev server) together with the Web Api on IIS kestrel on the same port. I don't think so... This question was not if you can put the angular cli project structure in Asp.net Core project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that we have to accept on the local host environment to have 2 local host servers running together when developing. Ng serve with webpack dev server for the client code (angular app) and iis express with kestrel for web api or MVC... This way you can use hot module replacement with ng serve.